# Adding a component to the render tree via an event handler, the component doesn't seem to receive new props. Why is this?

Tags: reactjs

I have a context provider that I use to store a list of components. These components are rendered to a portal (they render absolutely positioned elements).

```
const A = ({children}) => {
  // [{id: 1, component: () => <div>hi</>}, {}, etc ]
  const [items, addItem] = useState([])

  return (
    <.Provider value={{items, addItem}}>
    {children}
    {items.map(item => createPortal(<Item />, topLevelDomNode))}
    </.Provider>
  )
}
```

Then, when I consume the context provider, I have a button that allows me to add components to the context provider state, which then renders those to the portal. This looks something like this:

```
const B = () => {
  const {data, loading, error} = useMyRequestHook(...)

  console.log('data is definitely updating!!', data) // i.e. props is definitely updating!

  return (
    <.Consumer>
    {({addItem}) => (
      <Button onClick={() => {
        addItem({
          id: 9,

          // This component renders correctly, but DOESN'T update when data is updated
          component: () => (
            <SomeComponent
              data={data} 
            />
          )
        })
       }}>
        click to add component
      </Button>
    )}
    </.Consumer>
  )
}
```

Component `B` logs that the data is updating quite regularly. And when I click the button to add the component to the `items` list stored as state in the provider, it then renders as it should.

But the components in the `items` list don't re-render when the data property changes, even though these components receive the data property as props. I have tried using the class constructor with `shouldComponentUpdate` and the the component is clearly not receiving new props.

Why is this? Am I completely abusing react?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason is this.

Passing a component is not the same as rendering a component. By passing a component to a parent element, which then renders it, that component is used to render a child of the parent element and NOT the element where the component was defined.

Therefore it will never receive prop updates from where I expected it - where the component was defined. It will instead receive prop updates from where it is rendered (although the data variable is actually not coming from props in this case, which is another problem).

However, because of where it is defined. it IS forming a closure over the the props of where it is defined. That closure results in access to the data property.